# A conjectural trigonometric identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-identities, trigonometric-sums

Recently, I formulated the following conjecture which seems novel.

**Conjecture**. For any positive odd integer $n$, we have the identity
$$\sum_{j,k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\cos 2\pi j/n+\cos 2\pi k/n}=\frac{n^2}2.\tag{1}$$

Using Galois theory, I see that the sum is a rational number. The identity $(1)$ has some equivalent versions, for example,
$$\sum_{0\le j<k\le n-1}\frac1{\cos 2\pi j/n+\cos 2\pi k/n}=\frac n4\left(n-(-1)^{(n-1)/2}\right)\tag{2}$$
and
$$\sum_{1\le j<k\le n-1}\frac1{\cos 2\pi j/n+\cos 2\pi k/n}=-\frac{n-(-1)^{(n-1)/2}}4\left(n+(-1)^{(n-1)/2}2\right).\tag{3}$$
It is easy to check $(1)$-$(3)$ numerically.

**Question.** How to prove the conjecture?

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: If we put $n=8$ in the sum under consideration, then up to Maple and Mathematica we face with division by zero. E.g. restart;
n := 8;
add(add(1/(cos(2*Pi* j/n) + cos(2*Pi* k/n)), k = 0 .. n - 1), j = 0 .. n - 1); Error, numeric exception: division by zero

Comment: @user64494 but the conjecture was about odd integers

Comment: @Fedor Petrov: Thank you. Where do the below proofs use it?

Comment: @user64494 everywhere:) for even $n$ we indeed have zero denominators (say, for $j=0,k=n/2$ and others), it is senseless. In both below solutions the logarithmic derivative of some polynomial at some point is calculated, and for even $n$ this point would be a root of the polynomial.

Comment: The identity (1)  is a special case of a much more general result, see Theorem 1.2 of my preprint http://arxiv.org/abs/1908.02155.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following argument is very short, but bit tricky, so I remain it along with the previous answer.

Actually this sum quickly factorizes: using $\cos (x+y)+\cos (x-y)=2\cos x\cos y$ and denoting $(j+k)\cdot \frac{n+1}2=a,(j-k)\cdot \frac{n+1}2=b$ we get $$\cos 2\pi j/n+\cos 2\pi k/n=2\cos 2\pi a/n \cdot \cos 2\pi b/n.$$
Here $j, k, a, b$ may be considered as residues modulo $n$ ($\cos 2\pi a/n$ depends only on   $a$ modulo $n$), and the map $(j,k)\mapsto (a,b)$ is bijective on $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$, thus
$$
2\sum_{j,k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\cos 2\pi j/n+\cos 2\pi k/n}=\sum_{a,b=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\cos 2\pi a/n\cdot \cos 2\pi b/n}=\left(\sum_{a=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\cos 2\pi a/n}\right)^2.
$$
It remains to calculate the sum $\sum_{a=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\cos 2\pi a/n}$. Denoting $\omega=e^{2\pi i/n}$ we get 
$$
\sum_{a=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\cos 2\pi a/n}=\sum_{a=0}^{n-1}\frac{2\omega^a}{1+\omega^{2a}}=
\sum_{a=0}^{n-1}\frac{\omega^a+\omega^{(2n+1)a}}{1+\omega^{2a}}=\\
\sum_{a=0}^{n-1} (\omega^a-\omega^{3a}+\dots+(-1)^{(n-1)/2}\omega^{na}+\dots+\omega^{(2n-1)a})=(-1)^{(n-1)/2}n,
$$
since the geometric progressions $\sum_{a=0}^{n-1} \omega^{ma}$ sums up to $$\sum_{a=0}^{n-1} \omega^{ma}=\begin{cases}0& \text{for}\, m\, \text{not divisible by}\, n\\
n& \text{for}\, m\, \text{divisible by}\, n.
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 54):

Let $T_n$ be the $n$-th Chebyshev polynomial, so that
$$T_n(x)-1=\prod_{j=1}^n(x-\cos 2\pi j/n).$$
Taking a logarithmic derivative we have
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{x-\cos 2\pi j/n}=\frac{T_n'(x)}{T_n(x)-1}.$$
For $x=-\cos 2\pi k/n$, we easily find $T_n(x)=-1$. We therefore have
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\cos 2\pi k/n+\cos 2\pi j/n}=\frac{T_n'(-\cos 2\pi k/n)}{2}.$$
Now the derivative of $T_n$ is equal to $nU_{n-1}$, where $U_{n-1}$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind, satisfying $U_{n-1}(\cos t)=\frac{\sin nt}{\sin t}$.

For $k\neq 0$, at $t=2\pi k/n+\pi$, so that $\cos t=-\cos 2\pi k/n$, we get $U_{n-1}(-\cos 2\pi k/n)=\frac{\sin(2\pi k+n\pi)}{\sin(2\pi k/n+\pi)}=0$. For $k=0$, we have to take a limit at $t\to\pi$ and we find $U_{n-1}(1)=n$. Therefore we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\cos 2\pi k/n+\cos 2\pi j/n}=\frac{T_n'(1)}{2}=\frac{n^2}{2}.$$

Answer (score 30):

Denote $\omega=e^{2\pi i/n}$, then $\Omega=\{\omega^k:k=0,\ldots,n-1\}$ is the set of roots of the polynomial $f(t):=t^n-1$, $-\Omega=\{-\omega^k:k=0,\ldots,n-1\}$ the set of roots of $g(t):=t^n+1$. We start with the identity
$$
\eta(t):=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{t+\omega^k}=\frac{g'(t)}{g(t)}=\frac{nt^{n-1}}{t^n+1}. \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(1)
$$
Your initial sum is $$2\sum_{j,k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\omega^k+\omega^{-k}+\omega^j+\omega^{-j}}=2\sum_{j,k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{(\omega^k+\omega^{j})(1+\omega^{-j-k})}.$$
Fix $j+k\equiv a\pmod n$, and change the order of summation from $(j,k)$ to $(a,k)$. We get
$$
\sum_{a=0}^{n-1}\frac1{1+\omega^{-a}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac2{\omega^k+\omega^{a-k}}.
$$
Consider the inner sum. Denote $t_{\pm}(a)=\pm i\omega^{a/2}$ so that 
$$\frac2{\omega^k+\omega^{a-k}}=\frac1{\omega^k+t_+(a)}+\frac1{\omega^k+t_-(a)}$$
and by (1) we get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac2{\omega^k+\omega^{a-k}}=n\left(\frac{t_+(a)^{n-1}}{t_+(a)^n+1}+\frac{t_-(a)^{n-1}}{t_-(a)^n+1}\right)=nt_+(a)^{n-1}=n(-1)^{\frac{n-1}2}\omega^{\frac{n-1}2 a}.
$$
So it remains to calculate the sum
$$
n(-1)^{\frac{n-1}2}\sum_{a=0}^{n-1} \frac{\omega^{\frac{n-1}2 a}}{1+\omega^{-a}}=
n(-1)^{\frac{n-1}2}\sum_{z\in \Omega}\frac{z^{\frac{n+1}2}}{1+z}.
$$
Denote $m=\frac{n+1}2$. We get
$$
\sum_{z\in \Omega} \frac{z^m}{z+1}=
\sum_{z\in \Omega} \frac{z^m-(-1)^m+(-1)^m}{z+1}=
(-1)^m\cdot \frac{n}2+\sum_{z\in \Omega} (z^{m-1}-z^{m-2}+\ldots+(-1)^{m-1})=\\
(-1)^m\cdot \frac{n}2+(-1)^{m-1}\cdot n=(-1)^{m-1}\cdot \frac{n}2
$$
and your conjecture follows.